# linq2db Insert ? error ColumnMapping

Tags: c#, insert, linq2db

I try use linq2db for insert data? but get error

Table class

```
[Table(Schema="inf", Name="InformMessageLog")]
public partial class InformMessageLog
{
    [Identity             ] public int      ID             { get; set; }// int 
    [Column,   NotNull    ] public DateTime Date           { get; set; } // datetime
    [Column,   NotNull    ] public int      StudentID      { get; set; }// int 
    [Column,      Nullable] public string   ContactName    { get; set; } // nvarchar(max)
    [Column,      Nullable] public string   ContactPhone   { get; set; } // nvarchar(max)
    [Column,      Nullable] public string   ContactMail    { get; set; }// nvarchar(max) 
    [Column,   NotNull    ] public string   EventPoint     { get; set; } // nvarchar(50)
    [Column,   NotNull    ] public string   Template       { get; set; } // nvarchar(max)
    [Column,   NotNull    ] public string   Link           { get; set; } // nvarchar(100)
    [Column,   NotNull    ] public string   Status         { get; set; } // nvarchar(100)
    [Column,      Nullable] public bool?    TechnicalError { get; set; } // bit
    [Column,      Nullable] public string   CampaingId     { get; set; } // nvarchar(max)
}
```

my code

```
List<InformMessageLog> result = new List<InformMessageLog>();
result = ....; //form list result
try
    {
        using (var db = new IntegrationSqlDbDB())
        {
            db.BulkCopy(result);
        }
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        loger.LogError("Failed to set log from db " + e.Message);
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Failed to set log from db  - " + e.Message);
    }
```

result Data

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Date": "2018-04-13T00:00:00+00:00",
    "StudentID": 76769,
    "ContactName": "XXXXXXX XXXXXXX",
    "ContactPhone": "-",
    "ContactMail": "XXX@mail.ru",
    "EventPoint": "loyality",
    "Template": "1806123",
    "Link": "unisender",
    "Status": "-",
    "TechnicalError": false,
    "CampaingId": "1594676730"
  }
]
```

error

> The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in
>   the source or destination.

I checked all types and made a copypaste of the column names, but the problem remained. Could there be an issue in the ID column? How to correctly pass it to the bulkCopy structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While SQL Server column names are case-insensitive by default, bulk copy is case-sensitive. You need to check column names in database and if they differ by case from C# properties - put db names into column attribute.

Answer (score 1):

To try to pass the ID column, you can try the BulkCopyOptions:

```
db.BulkCopy(new BulkCopyOptions { KeepIdentity = true }, result);
```

So, in this case the insertion of all the list will keep the identity that you gave before.

Also, instead of "bit" in column type, try to use boolean.

PS: This option is working in SQL Provider. If you are using PostgreSQL, you need to update the linq2db to version 2.0.0.0 beta4, or some pre-releases.